# Chart duplicates series when updating from DataGrid

Tags: mysql, vb.net, charts

Have been trying to link my DataGrid to a chart. I eventually linked it but when the DataGrid updates (via timer) the chart series duplicates. Can you all check my code and tell me what's wrong or what I am missing?

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim areacode As Integer
    Call Classko.connect()
    MyConnect = Classko.conn
    Call Initialize_RecordSource()

    MySQLCmd.Connection = MyConnect
    Sql = "SELECT AreaCode,Percentage FROM tblencode "
    Sql = Sql & "Group By(AreaCode)"
    MySQLCmd.CommandText = Sql
    MyDA.SelectCommand = MySQLCmd
    MyDA.Fill(MyDataTable)
    MyData = MySQLCmd.ExecuteReader
    dgChart.DataSource = MyDataTable
    dgChart.Refresh()
    chtStatus.DataBind()

    While MyData.Read
        chtStatus.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(MyData.GetString("AreaCode"), MyData.GetString("Percentage"))
        chtStatus.Series.Add("Series1")
        chtStatus.Series("Series1").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        chtStatus.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Minimum = 10
        chtStatus.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Maximum = 100
        chtStatus.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Interval = 10
        chtStatus.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1
        chtStatus.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IntervalType = areacode + 1
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit,just new member here.

Comment: It would seem you add the series on every timer tick : `chtStatus.Series.Add("Series1")`, i'm suprised this doesn't throw an exception actually. You only need to add the series to the chart once, after that the chart should automatically update when you add a point like you do here : `chtStatus.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(MyData.GetString("AreaCode"), MyData.GetString("Percentage"))`

Comment: Still it duplicates, what is needed for the series in the chart to be refreshed?